# What is wrong with my require config

Tags: requirejs

I am using require.js, all are correct as well. I see the js loads in the document. In case of consoling, I am getting all of the parameters apart from Backbone. Why is the Backbone not logged in the console?

Here is my code :

```
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl : "scripts",
        paths   : {
                    "jquery"    :"lib/jquery-min",
                    "loDash"    :"lib/lodash-min",
                    "backBone"  :"lib/backbone-min" 
                        //this is exist load in document header, not console
                  }
    });

    require(["jquery","loDash","backBone"], function($,_,bB){
        console.log($,_,bB);//jquery, underscore console correctly.
// 3rd one "bB" - stand for backbone, it console as undefined - why?

    });
```

I am getting loaded all the js fine, including Backbone, on the document.

Answer (score 1):

I added the shim, and it works fine.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl : "scripts",
    paths   : {
                "jquery"    :"lib/jquery-min",
                "loDash"    :"lib/lodash-min",
                "backBone"  :"lib/backbone-min"
              },
    shim    : {
                  "backBone":{
                    deps    :["loDash"],
                    exports :"Backbone"
                  }
              }
});

require(["jquery","loDash","backBone"], function ($,_,bB) {
    console.log($,_,bB);
});
```